# Applet execution fails on line arguments

Tags: java, applet

i do face a strange behavior, after having updated my jdk/jre. After installation any applet i try to execute is running into the same IllegalArgumentException. I have enabled the java console debugging features and have found a strange entry, which i assume is causing the problem. See below:

```
basic: LaunchDesc.selectJRE(false, false) returning selected jre: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_51
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: -agentpath:"D:\progz\NetBeans 7.2.1\profiler\lib\deployed\jdk15\windows-amd64\profilerinterface.dll=D:\progz\NetBeans 7.2.1\profiler\lib",5140 
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.51 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

basic: LaunchDesc location: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp
basic: exception: Syntax Error: Unbalanced quotes in command line arguments.
ExitException[ 3]java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Syntax Error: Unbalanced quotes in command line arguments
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The -agentpath argument is passed in, unfortunately i neither know where it's been set nor why my old jre/jdk were not causing this problem.

Thanks for help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

this setting is probably configured in the "Configure Java" control panel.

Go to system control -> Configure Java -> Tab "Java" -> press the button "show" (or so).

There you have two tabs: User & System

It is possible that these parameters are set in either one.
You can simply change or remove them there.

Note: You have to restart your Java VM completely for this change to take effect.